# ¿Cómo hago extraer el valor de un input type file? jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

El problema es que intento hacer que al presionar un botón "`button`" me presione a la véz el `input type="file"` , lo logro hacer pero el valor de ese `input type="file"` no me sale, la única manera de que me salga es que lo haga directo desde el `"input type="file"` directamente, pero no lo quiero así he visto otros ejemplos sencillos, les dejo un ejemplo de lo que he hecho.

```
$('#id_button').click(function(){
   $('#id_input').click();
});
```

Con eso me sirve y al presionar ese botón me sale la ventana de seleccionar archivo pero no me almacena el valor, osea el nombre de ese archivo pero si lo hago directamente si me sirve.

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve]? No acabo de entender el escenario